# Android how to check if the Launched App has been closed?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, android-intent

In my App. I will list all the Games installed on the device.

I want to know when I launch a game, is this game has been closed. If so then Force my app to come up to foreground.

This in the onClick:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AppInfo app = (AppInfo) v.getTag();
        Intent LaunchIntent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        Log.w(TAG, "onClick > app: " + app + " \nLaunchIntent: " + LaunchIntent);
    };
```

Here is the log

```
onClick > 
app: com.myapp.screen.GameSelectFragment$AppInfo@1d32ed66 
LaunchIntent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.supercell.clashofclans cmp=com.supercell.clashofclans/.GameApp }
```

So for example:

When Click in clashofclans, I will launch the app (MyApp goes to background),
If the user press the home button or anything that sends clashofclans to the backgroup. Then I want to force MyApp to come to Foreground.

thanks